# Which of the two "ands" goes with "between"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

**[SOURCE](https://www.britannica.com/topic/The-Canterbury-Tales)**

I read this online,

> The pilgrimage, which in medieval practice combined a fundamentally religious purpose with the secular benefit of a spring vacation, made possible **extended consideration of the relationship between** the pleasures **and** vices of this world **and** the spiritual aspirations for the next.

The confusing part is whether it refers to "consideration ***of*** the relationship between the pleasure and vices of this world ***and*** ***of*** the spiritual aspirations" or "consideration of the relationship ***between*** ...of this world ***and*** the spiritual aspirations"?  Which one of the two ***ands***  goes together with ***between***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your passage is talking about the *secular* and the *spiritual* throughout. For example

> *religious* purpose... *spring vacation*

so it is the "relationship **between**"

> the pleasures and vices of this world

and

> the spiritual aspirations for the next.